# Delete excess Crystal Reports instances without deleting the recurring reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-server

### Background

Using Crystal Reports Server 2008, SP5.

Crystal normally stores instances of all reports run, which can make a database fill up quickly.

However, it has an option for each folder to "delete excess instances". This seems like a great feature.

...Except that Crystal Reports seems to think of the scheduled reports themselves as "instances", and therefore deletes the instances themselves as part of cleanup, killing the scheduled report.

### Question

How can I delete excess instances in Crystal Reports automatically, without deleting the scheduled reports themselves?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a repository query:

```
...
/// get report instances that are NOT recurring
String commandText = @"SELECT * FROM ci_infoObjects WHERE si_kind = 'CrystalReport' AND si_instance=1 AND si_recurring=0";
/// assumes that you have a valid infoStore object
InfoObjects infoObjects = infoStore.query(commandText);
foreach (InfoObject infoObject in infoObjects) {
  /// delete object
  infoObject.delete;
}
/// save changes to repository
infoStore.commit;
```